# HttpServletRequest.getParameter not working

Tags: angularjs, http, tomcat, servlets

I have an older web site that I maintain and have not touched in months (verified by checking timestamps including OS, Java, servlet filters, web.xml etc.) This morning it suddenly stopped working. I tracked it down to this:

JavaScript:

```
var fd = new FormData();  
fd.append('action', 'getUserConfiguration')     
// sent using AngularJS $http service
```

Fiddler:

```
POST https://X.com/X HTTP/1.1
Host: X.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 157
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: https://X.com
Authorization: Bearer <omitted for clarity>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBefuvbQ5DT0S3swB
Referer: https://X.com/x.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: <omitted for clarity>

------WebKitFormBoundaryBefuvbQ5DT0S3swB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"

getUserConfiguration
------WebKitFormBoundaryBefuvbQ5DT0S3swB--
```

As far as I can tell, so far so good? But:

Java8 / Tomcat7:

```
@MultipartConfig
public class X extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {  
        String action = httpRequest.getParameter("action");
```

The problem is that action is null. I tried dumping out the raw content from getInputStream() and it is also an empty string.

Any ideas?

Comment: you left your ip address in the user-agent string

Comment: In case anybody cares, I finally figured this out. Disk was 100% full on one volume and this prevented Tomcat's Multipart function from working. With getParameter(), it fails silently. With getParts(), you get a meaningful message that makes it obvious. So the trick is to try getParts() even if you don't expect anything other than simple String parameters. Cheers

Comment: You could post this as an answer and accept it, to conserve this knowledge for the future. Or file an issue with Tomcat to make `getParameter()` fail less silently. Or both.